# Ruby - Why is this reverse sort not working correctly?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have code that's sorting an array of arrays of objects based on a common method/value all objects share, but it's not quite working correctly. The code is supposed to give me the X highest totals based on the added value, but if I do `.first(10)` it misses the top values. If I do `first(50)`, I see more, but there's still some higher values missing. What's going on here, shouldn't my sort and reverse ensure that `first(x)` will return the array with the highest sum? It seems `first` is grabbing without the sort being completed.

```
some_array = old_array.sort_by{ |ar| ar.sum(&:ppd) }.reverse.first(10)
```

Here's an example of what old_array looks like in case it adds clarity

```
old_array = [
             [ obj1, obj2 ], #obj1.ppd + obj2.ppd = 50
             [ obj3, obj4 ], #sum ppd = 55
             [ obj5, obj6 ], #sum ppd = 60, does not show in first(10)
             ... #and so on with dozens more
            ]
```

Comment: The code you've posted here looks fine. If there is a problem, it's not in the example you've given us.

Comment: The code is exactly as it is in my application, the only thing that's different is the variable name and example array for the sake of clarity. I guess I could look into my source array but that doesn't seem to be the issue since upping the first() value uncovers greater results.

Comment: We can't tell with what you've given us. We'd need to understand what `ar.sum(&:ppd)` always returns. Try looking at `old_array.map{ |ar| ar.sum(&:ppd) }` and make sure those are sane.

Comment: @theTinMan you're right, my issue was within the values I was looking up there... thanks for the help and ensuring my Ruby wasn't the issue!